# In After Effects how can I generate the value of an opposite x position and then send that value to an effect on another layer?

Tags: after-effects, automation

e.g.

my composition width is 4480

I have a layer with a gradient ramp effect with an x start positon of 1026 and I want to generate and store the value of the x position on the other side of the composition which would be 3454.

Then have a duplicate of that effect on another layer get the stored value or have the value sent to it

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're asking to do is simple using [Expressions](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/after-effects/user-guide.html/uk/after-effects/using/expression-basics.ug.html).
If you alt-click on the stop watch of any keyframe-able control you can write an expression to connect that control to another control.
So if you want to control the end of ramp's x position using the start of ramp's x position in your example, it would be:

```
x = 4480-(effect("Gradient Ramp")("Start of Ramp")[0]);
y = 1080;
[x,y];
```

[image: screengrab]

The [0] indicates an [array](https://aeexpressions.blogspot.com/2006/07/lesson-2-arrays-and-variables.html) - it means "take the x position of the "start of ramp", which has two values, x and y, which can be called as [0] or [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CszPN.png) in the array.

To duplicate this in another layer, duplicate your first layer using cmd+D, then add an Expression to the start of ramp in the duplicated layer:

[image: grab2]

You can use the [pickwhip](https://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/pick-whip-adobe-after-effects/) to select the control you want to enter into the expression

Comment: A more robust way of doing this is to avoid hard-coded constants and use `x = thisComp.width - (effect("Gradient Ramp")("Start of Ramp")[0]);` and `y = thisComp.height;`. You can use this in any comp and it will be right.